The Lie algebra of an algebraic group
I have a question concerning different visions of the Lie algebra of an algebraic group. To be more specific, let $G = \operatorname{Spec}(H)$ be a smooth (finitely generated) algebraic group over a field $\mathbb{K}$. We denote by $\epsilon : H \to \mathbb{K}$ the counit. The definition of the Lie algebra of $G$ I have seen goes as follows :
introduce $H^+ := ker(\epsilon)$ and then define:
\begin{equation*}
\mathfrak{g}^* := \frac{H^+}{{H^+}^2}
\end{equation*}
The Lie algebra of $G$ is then defined by:
\begin{equation*}
\mathfrak{g} := Hom_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathfrak{g}^* ,\mathbb{K}) \cong Der_{\epsilon}(H,\mathbb{K})
\end{equation*}
where $Der_{\epsilon}(H,\mathbb{K})$ is the set of derivations relative to the counit, i.e. linear maps $\xi : H \to \mathbb{K}$ such that $\xi (hh') = \xi(h) \epsilon (h') + \epsilon(h) \xi(h')$ for all $h,h' \in H$.
In some way, the Lie algebra is defined as a set of derivations, which makes me feel a link with the tangent space at the unit or the set of left-invariant vector fields like in the case of Lie groups. However, I am not able make those statements precise.
Could someone please try to explain the intuition behind those definitions?

Let $X = \text{Spec } R$ be an affine scheme over a field $K$ and let $x \in X$ be a $K$-point, represented by an evaluation homomorphism $e_x : R \to K$, whose kernel is a maximal ideal $m_x$. The Zariski cotangent space of $X$ at $x$, which we can denote $T_x^{\ast}(X)$, is the quotient $m_x/m_x^2$, and the Zariski tangent space $T_x(X)$ is its $K$-linear dual $(m_x/m_x^2)^{\ast}$.
As you say this can be identified with a suitable space of derivations, and then the definition you give of the Lie algebra of an algebraic group is precisely the Zariski tangent space at the identity.
Here is another way of thinking about this definition which I think is more intuitive. Roughly speaking a pair $(x, v)$ consisting of a point and a tangent vector at that point is an "infinitesimal one-parameter family of points." In algebraic geometry it is possible to make this completely precise, by considering points over $K[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$, or equivalently homomorphisms $R \to K[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$. If you write down explicitly what such a homomorphism is, it is exactly a pair consisting of the evaluation homomorphism $e_x : R \to K$ at a $K$-point together with a derivation $D_x$ with respect to $e_x$ (more precisely the homomorphism is $e_x + \varepsilon D_x$). So you can define the entire tangent bundle at once to consist of the set of homomorphisms $R \to K[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ (this can be upgraded to a scheme but we don't need it here). This has a natural quotient map to the set of $K$-points $R \to K$, and then we can define the tangent space at a point to be the fiber of this map above a given point. This is equivalent to the above definition. It also does not require $X$ to be affine.
